# How to check if Workload Identity is enabled in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

Pretty much the title. I used `kubectl config view` but didn't see anything that would make me know whether it is enabled or not. I am also using google kubernetes engine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a web page with a great solution to this problem: https://medium.com/google-cloud/mapping-kubernetes-service-accounts-to-gcp-iams-using-workload-identity-b53496d543e0

If you go to the end, they demonstrate testing WI by launching a gsutil container that you can download from google. You can then use this dockerized version of gsutil to test connectivity to buckets straight from your kubernetes infrastructure.